# Merge or append multiple Keras TimeseriesGenerator objects into one

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to make a LSTM model. The data is coming from a csv file that contains values for multiple stocks.

I can't use all the rows as they appear in the file to make sequences because each sequence is only relevant in the context of its own stock, so I need to select the rows for each stock and make the sequences based on that.

I have something like this:

```
for stock in stocks:

    stock_df = df.loc[(df['symbol'] == stock)].copy()
    target = stock_df.pop('price')

    x = np.array(stock_df.values)
    y = np.array(target.values)

    sequence = TimeseriesGenerator(x, y, length = 4, sampling_rate = 1, batch_size = 1)
```

That works fine, but then I want to merge each of those sequences into a bigger one that I will use for training and that contains the data for all the stocks.

It is not possible to use append or merge because the function return a generator object, not a numpy array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### EDIT: **New answer:**

---

So what I've ended up doing is to do all the preprocessing manually and save an .npy file for each stock containing the preprocessed sequences, then using a manually created generator I make batches like this:

```
class seq_generator():

  def __init__(self, list_of_filepaths):
    self.usedDict = dict()
    for path in list_of_filepaths:
      self.usedDict[path] = []

  def generate(self):
    while True: 
      path = np.random.choice(list(self.usedDict.keys()))
      stock_array = np.load(path) 
      random_sequence = np.random.randint(stock_array.shape[0])
      if random_sequence not in self.usedDict[path]:
        self.usedDict[path].append(random_sequence)
        yield stock_array[random_sequence, :, :]

train_generator = seq_generator(list_of_filepaths)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(seq_generator.generate(),
                                               output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), 
                                               output_shapes=(n_timesteps, n_features)) 

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

Where `list_of_filepaths` is simply a list of paths to preprocessed .npy data.

---

This will:

- Load a random stock's preprocessed .npy data
- Pick a sequence at random
- Check if the index of the sequence has already been used in `usedDict`
- If not:

  - Append the index of that sequence to `usedDict` to keep track as to not feed the same data twice to the model
  - Yield the sequence

This means that the generator will feed a single unique sequence from a random stock at each "call", enabling me to use the `.from_generator()` and `.batch()` methods from Tensorflows [Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) type.

---

### **Original answer:**

I think the answer from @TF_Support is slightly missing the point. If I understand your question It's not as if you want to train one model pr. stock, **you want one model trained on the entire dataset**.

If you have enough memory you could manually create the sequences and hold the entire dataset in memory. The issue I'm facing is similar, I simply can't hold everything in memory: [Creating a TimeseriesGenerator with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177311/creating-a-timeseriesgenerator-with-multiple-inputs).

Instead I'm exploring the possibility of preprocessing all data for each stock seperately, saving as .npy files and then using a generator to load a random sample of those .npy files to batch data to the model, I'm not entirely sure how to approach this yet though.

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing so I'm marking it as correct. I ended up writing my own generator as it doesn't look like there's a way to use TimeseriesGenerator() for this use case. You are correct that what I wanted to do was use the whole dataset for training.

Answer (score 1):

For the scenario, you want **to merge each of those sequences into a bigger one that contains the data for all the stocks and will be used for training**.

You can **append** the created **TimeSeriesGenerators into a Python List**.

```
stock_timegenerators = []
for stock in stocks:
    stock_df = stock.copy()
    features = stock_df.pop('symbol')
    target = stock_df.pop('price')
  
    x = np.array(stock_df.values)
    y = np.array(target.values)

    # sequence = TimeseriesGenerator(x, y, length = 4, sampling_rate = 1, batch_size = 1)
    stock_timegenerators.append(TimeseriesGenerator(x, y, length = 4, sampling_rate = 1, batch_size = 1))
```

The output of this will be an **appended TimeSeriesGenerator** that you can use by **iterating** the **list** or **reference** by **index**.

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator at 0x7eff62c699b0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator at 0x7eff62c6eba8>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator at 0x7eff62c782e8>]
```

Also having **Multiple Keras Timeseries** means that you're training **Multiple LSTM Models** for each stock. 
You can also use this approach in dealing with multiple models efficiently.

```
lstm_models = []
for time_series_gen in stock_timegenerators:

    # lstm_models.append(create_model()) : You could create everything using functions

    # Or in the loop like this.
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape = (n_input, n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(loss ='mse', optimizer = 'adam')

    model.fit(time_series_gen, steps_per_epoch= 1, epochs = 5)
    
    lstm_models.append(model)
```

This would output a list of models appended and easily referenced using the index.

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x7eff62c7b748>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x7eff6100e160>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x7eff63dc94a8>]
```

This way you can create **Multiple LSTM Models** that have **different Time Series Generators** for **different stocks**.

Hope this helps you.